# My website payment page is saying insecure

Tags: google-chrome, https, google-chrome-extension, httpwebrequest, cakephp-1.3

I am getting this error while going to my pay deposit page..

```
[blocked]The page at https:linkurl ran insecure content from http://linkurl/404/
```

While doing an enrollment on Google Chrome after clicking on Pay Deposit button of the pop up then a blank page is displaying with main menu. however its working fine on other browsers including IE8.

I have tird this ----If your page is always accessed by secure url (https) then you might try accessing the secure versions of those include files. I think you can just use https: in place of http: in the url for those two files.

If you want to get fancy, you can check to see if the page is secure and pick either the secure or non-secure version of the link. I can post a sample of that if you need it.

No solutions!!
Guide me!!

Comment: Make sure you'll load every thing on the page will be from `https`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like some sort of asset on that page is being loaded in through `HTTP` when it should be loaded in through `HTTPS`. I would check all of your images, CSS, and JavaScript files and make sure they are linked as `HTTPS`. Or better yet, look into [Protocol Relative URLs](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) to avoid this problem.